# How to output a bat file and execute it?

Tags: export, syntax, output

I tried to write a bat file which helped me rename files.
Command to do this in that file is "ren file1 file2" which is equivalent to RenameFile[file1,file2].

```
renameFiles[directory_, files_, rename_] :=
 Module[{list, i = 1, newfiles},
  SetDirectory[directory];
  newfiles = ("ren " <> #) & /@ FileNames[files];
  list = Table[
    " " <> rename <> ToString[i] <> ".png", {i, 1, Length[newfiles]}];
  While[i <= Length[newfiles], 
   newfiles[[i]] = newfiles[[i]] <> list[[i]]; i++];
  Return[newfiles]
  ]
a = renameFiles["E:\\Download Pictures", ___, "save"]
Export["E:\\Download Pictures\rename.txt", a]
```

The renameFiles[] has three arguments which take the path, files in that path and name I want to change to respectively, and then convert them into a list "ren file1 file2". Afterwards, I output it as a txt file. I tried to output it as a bat file, however it displays error after I do:
`Export["E:\\Download Pictures\rename.bat", a]`

Therefore, I attempt to do that in a different way, which renames "rename.txt" afterwards by doing:
`RenameFiles["E:\\Download Pictures\rename.txt","E:\\Download Pictures\rename.bat"]`

So, now, I have my "rename.bat" file.
I try to use `SystemOpen["E:\\Download Pictures\rename.bat"]` to execute it. However, it cannot work well, and I have to do it by clicking the file.

My questions are: 1. Sometimes I get the syntax: `OpenWrite::noopen: "Cannot open \!\(\"E:\\\\Download Pictures\\\\nename.txt\"\). "` , how can I fix this?
2. Is this the only way I can output a bat file.
3. and, how can I execute via MMA.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

Not sure why you'd want to go through all the machinations of creating a batch file instead of just doing it directly with `RenameFile`, but... using your function, e.g.:

```
rn = renameFiles["c:\\users\\rasher\\documents\\", "*.xxx", "blah"];

Export["c:\\users\\rasher\\documents\\ren.bat", rn, "Text"];

SetDirectory["c:\\users\\rasher\\documents\\"];

Run["ren.bat"]
```

Will do it.